# How to install Cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to install Cocoapods, but I receive the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
```

I have tried many suggestions to solve this, but nothing helped.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is a very general description, provide data like:
- OS version
- Cocoapods version you are trying to install
- Terminal output of the error
- Things you did while trying to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try To use

> sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin

or Check this link https://medium.com/@javedmultani16/getting-error-while-installing-cocoapods-you-dont-have-write-permissions-for-the-usr-bin-9208a4d2141d